# load modal using $http in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to load data in modal (ui.bootstrap.modal) with the help of angularJs.For Example i send request through post method and data retrieve successfully and now i want to load it into modal.Here is my code

```
var MainAdmin = angular.module('MainAdmin', ['ui.bootstrap']);
function MainAdminController($scope, $http, $modal) {
$scope.LoadTypesView = function() {
            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'load.php', 
                data    : dataArray,  
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }  
            })
                .success(function(data) {
                     if(data.result.status=="success")
                    {
                        $scope.Type = data.result.response; // Type is an array which is defined. 
$modal.open({
                            templateUrl: 'UserTypeModal.html',
                            backdrop: true,
                            windowClass: 'modal',
                            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log, Type) {

                                $scope.SubmitUserType = function () {

                                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                                }
                                $scope.cancel = function () {
                                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                                };
                            }
                        });
                    }   
                });
         };
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
<h1><a href="" ng-click="LoadTypesView()">Types</a></h1>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="UserTypeModal.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>Define User Rights</h3>
    </div>
    <form ng-submit="SubmitUserType()">
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
    </form>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>

</script>
```

Kindly provide some example code
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Answer (score 0):

try this way. It's just like a simple sample

```
<div ng-repeat="inventory in Type  ">
<p>{{inventory.YourField}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply But i want this data to load into dialog box like [link](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)
<div ng-repeat="inventory in Type  ">
<p>{{inventory.YourField}}</p>
</div>